# Bayes Net. How are the values P(G | D,I) calculated?

Tags: probability-theory, bayesian-network

[Example Bayes Net](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xmkm8.png)

I have been looking into Bayesian Networks but I keep getting hung up on a simple dependence in most example problems which is how are the values in the conditional probability tables on the child node calculated? More specifically in the linked figure how are the values in the table for G calculated? It seems like these values would be dependent on I and D but it is not obvious to me. BTW I am fairly rusty on probability theory.

Comment: I think the values in the tables can be arbitrary. The tables specify the conditional distributions, and can be chosen to be whatever you want.

Comment: If that is the case how would this work in practice? In constructing a Bayes net like the one in the example would you need a dataset to populate every condition for every node? For low probability events this would seem difficult to sample. i.e. having an intelligent student take an easy test and get a bad grade would seem rare. You would need a lot of samples.

Comment: You use some method to estimate the parameters of your model. Here the parameters are the probabilities that go in the tables. Maximum likelihood estimation is a common approach in general, but I'm not sure if or how it is used for Bayesian networks. Bayesian networks can model arbitrarily complicated joint distributions of discrete random variables, so you probably need to assume your network is of a certain form, e.g. Markov, or a tree, in order to make computation feasible.